# Spring jpa did not successfully insert data in Runnable

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, runnable, executorservice

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(9);
    for(String s : list){
        DownLoadFileTask downLoadFileTask = new DownLoadFileTask(s);
        executor.submit(downLoadFileTask);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    logger.info("===================================================");
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I used ExecutorService to bulk download pictures in the service。

DownLoadFileTask.class as follows

```
public class DownLoadFileTask implements Runnable  {

@Resource
FileClassService fileClassService;

private String downUrl;

public DownLoadFileTask(String downUrl){
    this.downUrl = downUrl;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        String url = DownLoadFileUtils.downloadFile(downUrl,null);
        System.out.println("===================================" + url);
        FileClass file = new FileClass(url);
        file = fileClassService.save(file);
        System.out.println("===================================" + file.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When i run it， The log is not printed

`System.out.println("===================================" + file.toString());`

And there is no record in the database

I do not know how to fix it。Can someone help me?

Comment: It might be huge file which may not be downloaded in 1sec. Increase the time to 10 mins for e.g. and then optimize it further.

Comment: @SMA    But this document is not big, just some pictures only。Is there any other reason?